# Failing to compile supersimple code

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction, compilation, linker

I don't understand why but I'm failing to compile supersimple C code in two files when there are some references between them. I'm using Visual Studio 2010, opening Empy C++ project Here it is:

main.c:

```
extern void putc(char c);
int main() {
char c = ' ';
putc(c);
return;
}
```

anotherfile.c:

```
void putc(char c) {

}
```

I'm getting these errors:
[image: My errors]

I think it will be in some project configuration, but I don't have any idea where....

Please help.

Comment: Try to rename your `putc` to a different name. It might be a name-clash with `C`-function `putc`.

Comment: I tried. It did not help. Getting the same errors, but with changed name.

Comment: Try to clean your Project folder. I just tested your code in VC2012 and it worked for me...

Comment: I bet you're not using those exact files. There's a reference to `screen.obj` in the error message, and `anotherfile.c` (which I presume is `screen.c`) as written above does not refer to `main` or `_main` in any way.

Comment: That's true. The name of anotherfile.c is screen.c. I'm not referencing main, but error is there and that's what I think I have incorrect configuration. But I don't know in what way... The files in question are the only files in project.

Comment: I have compiled the code using gcc. There are no errors. Only a warning about putc(). The warning is "conflicting types for built-in-function 'putc' ".

Comment: @user35443: What you have posted here looks fine to me. I suggest that you check what you are really compiling. The problem is probably in some other bit of code.

Comment: So trying to find out what's the problem: it looks like compiler thinks that every object file needs its own _main method (is it possible?). It also looks like the object files I'm linking are taken as separate and I can't link them together to resolve each other. I've created new solution and I've put these files there... and it worked... So what can cause behaivor like this? What setting can do something like this?

Comment: @user35443 Since you have mentioned VC2012, can you try by disabling the precompiled headers option for the project and try?

Comment: I'@e disabled creating precompiled headers and it works. Thanks! BTW now I'm getting intellisense warnings... But I can endure intelisense. please post it as answer.

Comment: @user35443 Great... I have just posted it as an answer

Comment: Maybe you can provide just a small explanation why it works when I have disabled it. What if I need to use precompiled headers in future but I won't be able to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the VC2012 project, please **disable** the `Precompiled Headers` option. This should resolve the compilation issues faced by you.

Answer (score 1):

it work for me with default setting. Perhaps there is a problem with your .sln. Try to create a new empty **console project**, and add your files. If it still not work, send the error that you have when you build the exe.